# How to identify disturbed node in AVL tree?

Tags: c++, tree, avl-tree

I am coding an AVL insert function. Please tell me how can I identify a node whose balance is disturbed when inserting a new node? I know how to calculate the balance factor of any node. But if I added the node as a leaf how can I know about the ancestor node whose balance is disturbed? so that I can apply rotation to it. Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 4):

Once you add a leaf, you move up to parents one by one towards the root and update their height (or depth if you want). As you are updating the tree heights, you check if they go out of balance and you rebalance them. Then you continue moving upwards again.

This is an `O(log(n))` operation since the path from any leaf to the root in an AVL tree contains `O(log(n))` nodes and rebalancing a node is done in `O(1)`

Answer (score 2):

Once you get the balance factor (in my case, (height of left subtree - height of right subtree)),

- If balance factor is greater than 1, then the current node is unbalanced and we are either in Left Left case or left Right case. To check whether it is left left case or not, compare the newly inserted key with the key in left subtree root.
- If balance factor is less than -1, then the current node is
  unbalanced and we are either in Right Right case or Right Left case.
  To check whether it is Right Right case or not, compare the newly
  inserted key with the key in right subtree root.

Does this answer your question?